# Why ActionBar Drop Shadow is not working? Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, dropshadow

I am not using ActionBarSherlock.

I added android:windowContentOverlayto my styles.xml, but there is still no shadow at all.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/drawer_shadow</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppActionBarTheme" >
```

What did I miss?

Is it possible that I can add ActionBar Shadow programmatically?